# how to create pymol rename loop

Tags: loops, pymol

I would like to create a loop for changing interactions name in PyMol. But after one selection loop it crashes and doesn't work.

```
def get_dists(interactions): # interactions=([1,2], [3,4])

    for i in interactions:
        a = "////" + str(i[0]) + "/C2'"
        b = "////" + str(i[1]) + "/C2'"
        cmd.distance("(" + a + ")", "(" + b + ")")

        for j in range(1, 599):
            x = "dist" + "0" + str(j)
            y = str(i[0]) + " " + str(i[1])
            cmd.set_name(str(x), str(y))
```

In Pymol the default name of interactions is dist01, 02 , 03.

I want to change these to 1_3, 5_59, 4_8, (interaction between residue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is totally fine except for one thing: If PyMol doesn't succeed with set_name the whole script is aborted. When you change it to, it should work:

```
try:
    cmd.set_name(str(x), str(y))
except:
    print('failed to rename')
```

---

Some additional comments:

- `y = str(i[0]) + " " + str(i[1])` should be `y = str(i[0]) + "_" + str(i[1])`
- this line is probably for padding zeros `x = "dist" + "0" + str(j)`. This is only needed when `j` is a single digit, otherwise the name of the distance objects is `dist20` or `dist123`
- `cmd.set_name(str(x), str(y))` can be simplified to `cmd.set_name(x, y)` since `x` and `y` are already `strings`.